# B-Spline with increasing knot distance

Tags: reference-request, approximation-theory, spline

I'm trying to approximate a function $f(x)$ on $[0, M]$ that, in some sense, begins to rapidly "vary slower" as $x$ increases, i.e. its modulus of continuity (or the variation of its derivatives) decrease rapidly. Are there any known results of using B-Spline bases with geometrically spaced knots (or some other increasing spacing of knots)? For example, a geometric progression:
$$
t_i = \alpha \beta^i \qquad \beta > 1, i = 1, \dots, n
$$
or some polynomial progression:
$$
t_i = \alpha i^2, \qquad i = 1, \dots, n
$$